# How to purge user defined material cost in Oracle EBS

Tags: oracle-ebs, cost-management

Can anyone explain how to purge user-defined material costs from a given cost type in Oracle EBS 12.1.3?  The documentation says to run Purge Cost Information.

For the given cost type, all items have Based on Rollup flag checked.

I have run this program against the given cost type and with Purge Option set to 'Not based on rollup items, costs and controls.'  The program completes in a matter of seconds and does not affect any change - we still have user defined Material costs at the top of the costing form.  The job output and log contains no information regarding activity or error.

Then tried running Purge Cost Information again with option set to 'Based on rollup items, costs and control' - thinking this might work now, considering that all items are set to 'Based on Rollup.'  This time the program removed the entire cost type from the item setups.

We want the cost type to remain, just the user-defined material costs to go away.  Yes, we can delete these entries manually from form, but there are hundreds of records.  There must be a programmatic way to purge these entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way we were able to resolve this was to re-upload the user defined material cost at $0.  Not ideal, but achieves the overall goal.